# Rails localhost connecting to amazon s3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do you grant access to your amazon s3 bucket from your local machine? I keep getting this error:

```
Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden) excon.error.response :body => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AllAccessDisabled</Code><Message>All access to this object has been disabled</Message>
```

In the IAM console I have given myself AmazonS3FullAccess and AdministratorAccess policies.

In the S3 console under 'Permissions' I have this CORS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

However, in the S3 console, when I click on 'Add bucket policy' the policy editor is blank. Shouldn't the two policies created in the IAM console show up here? Or are they different things?

What policy should I add in the policy editor? I've tried creating one but I get many errors.

Comment: Are you connecting via HTTP or over XML?

Comment: There are several issues here... CORS config has *nothing* to do with access controls, IAM policies do not appear in the bucket policy because they aren't bucket policies.  Both IAM policies and bucket policies work together -- if either or both grant, permission is granted; if either or both deny, permission is denied.  Finally, `All access to this object has been disabled` implies that you are accessing the wrong bucket -- that error seems to appear when you access a bucket owned by an account is cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely is in your bucket policy.
As long as your localhost as the KEY and SECRET it shouldn't matter.

Try adding this policy to the IAM user you are connecting with:

```
{
    "Version": "2015-12-26",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What this does is allow the user to lookup that bucket name (top part) and then interact with all the folders `arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*`.

If you want to restrict that user to sub-folders just modify that part above.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thank you, I've added the policy to my IAM user but I still have the same error. Just to be clear I don't currently have any policies associated with the bucket. Should I add one? Also, what do you mean the by localhost as the key and secret?

Comment: It has suddenly started working, and I don't quite know how. I'm not sure, but I think it may be when I closed and reopened a terminal window. If a terminal can't "see" the s3_bucket environment variable, would that mean it also isn't getting sent in the request?

Comment: hard to answer without knowing your dev environment, that policy should have rid your 403 error though